# Doing PHP Submit and Fileupload from same button

Tags: php, html, file-upload, webforms

I am writing a page where a user can fill out form data, select two files for upload, and then hit Submit to pass the form data into the PHP page, and also the two files will be uploaded.

The problem is the submit button seems to be able to only be either a 'submit' or a 'File_Upload'. It can't do both... or can it?

Here is the gyst of HTML file (Just enough to get the point across... I hope)

```
  <form class='form' name="frm_new_session" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <div class='frm_row'>  
        <label>Title</label>  
        <input id="titleF" type='text' name="title" size='50' />  
        <input type="hidden" name="_chkuser" value="1"/>  
    </div>  
    <div class='frm_row'>  
        <label>Description</label>  
        <textarea id="descF" rows='3' cols='53' name="desc"></textarea>  
    </div>  
    <div class='frm_row'>  
        <label>Image</label>  
        <input id="imageF" type="file" name="uploadedimage">  
        <input type="hidden" name=MAX_FILE_SIZE" value='50000000'/>  
        </input> <br />  
    </div>  
    <div class='frm_row'>  
        <label>Session Media</label>  
        <input type='radio' id="mediaF" name="media" />  
        Upload: <input type='file' name="fileupload">  
        </input> <br />  
        <input type='radio' id="mediaF" name="media" />  
            Enter media URL:  
            <input type='text' size='75' name="mediaFile"/>  
        </input>  
    </div>                  
    <div class='frm_row'>  
        <input type="submit" value="Save Session"/>                     
        <div class='btn' type="submit" style='float: left;'>  
        <a href='#' id='btn_save_session'><span>Save Session</span></a>  
        <div class='kill_clear'></div>  
    </div>  
 </form>
```

I know I can do this using multiple forms, but I would like to avoid that and enjoy having just a single 'Save' button.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can definitely do both with one button. Not sure what you're doing wrong, but its certainly possible.  What do you get when you print_r($_POST) on the target page?

Comment: or when you `print_r($_FILES)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i don't understand the problem, the info will be in the $_POST array and the files in the $_FILES array.
however, you are missing a double quote in MAX_FILE_SIZE, i tested the following code, and it works :D

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
?>
  <form class='form' name="frm_new_session" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <div class='frm_row'>  
        <label>Title</label>  
        <input id="titleF" type='text' name="title" size='50' />  
        <input type="hidden" name="_chkuser" value="1"/>  
    </div>  
    <div class='frm_row'>  
        <label>Description</label>  
        <textarea id="descF" rows='3' cols='53' name="desc"></textarea>  
    </div>  
    <div class='frm_row'>  
        <label>Image</label>  
        <input id="imageF" type="file" name="uploadedimage">  
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value='50000000'/>  
        </input> <br />  
    </div>  
    <div class='frm_row'>  
        <label>Session Media</label>  
        <input type='radio' id="mediaF" name="media" />  
        Upload: <input type='file' name="fileupload">  
        </input> <br />  
        <input type='radio' id="mediaF" name="media" />  
            Enter media URL:  
            <input type='text' size='75' name="mediaFile"/>  
        </input>  
    </div>                  
    <div class='frm_row'>  
        <input type="submit" value="Save Session"/>                     
        <div class='btn' type="submit" style='float: left;'>  
        <a href='#' id='btn_save_session'><span>Save Session</span></a>  
        <div class='kill_clear'></div>  
    </div>  
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/add-news.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5242880" />
<input type="text" name="title" />
<input type="file" name="image" />
<textarea rows="40" cols="50" name="content"></textarea>
</form>
```

Try adding hidden field MAX_FILE_SIZE where value is max size of files in bytes.
It works for me.

What you mean by: "It can't do both", what are the indications?

Comment: hmm... well I actually have the MAX_FILE_SIZE in there.

Comment: Ideally I would like to be able to upload files, AND post input values using the same SUBMIT button.

Admittedly, my experience with PHP is a bit limited, but as I understand it, a file upload is only triggered when a button with action='file upload' is hit. Alternatively, form data is only submitted when the SUBMIT button has action='submit'.